# which way is correct way of checking not null variable

Tags: php, if-statement, null, is-empty

Which is the more effective way of checking whether `$value` is not null

```
if ($value > 0 && $value !== 'null') { }
```

or

```
if (empty($value)) { }
```

Comment: For checking null you can use `is_null()` function of php

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a duplicate of this somewhere..

Answer (score 2):

PHP has an elegant [`is_null`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) function to check if a variable is actually `NULL`.

```
if (is_null($value)) {
    // so something
}
```

[`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), on the other hand, checks for empty strings (`''`), zeroes (as integers, floating points or even the string `'0'`), `FALSE`, empty arrays, uninitialized variables and `NULL`s.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(!empty($value)){
 //do stuff
}else{
// do somthing else
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding at least some words explaining to the OP and to further readers of you answer why and how it does reply to the original question.